# .equals() seems not to work

Tags: android, equals

I am new to Android Studio and I have been creating a login form to open up the system settings.

I have made the form and gotten the form to pop-up once the button is pressed. However, the form for some reason always accepts the details entered, and always pops up with "Login Successful"..

I have been looking about online for the past couple of days now to see where I have gone wrong, but I just can't seem to find where in the code I have made a mistake?

I already have the code in order to open the setting page, but I have removed it just to show you all my code at the moment. (I have tested the open system settings part, and it works fine).

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton mShowDialog = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShowDialog);
    mShowDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_login, null);
            final EditText mUsername = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
            final EditText mPassword = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
            Button mLogin = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

            mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view_) {
                    if(!mUsername.getText().toString().equals("admin") && !mPassword.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                getString(R.string.success_login_msg),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                getString(R.string.error_login_msg),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

I am guessing I have gone wrong somewhere, but if anyone can give me a heads up to why this is happening, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to open Settings when the Login is Successful?

Comment: have you use `equalIgnoreCase()` and you are using `!`  condition have you checked this.?

Comment: it should like this `if(mUsername.getText().toString().equals("admin") && mPassword.getText().toString().equals("admin"))`

Comment: you are checking for if user name **is not** admin, and password **is not** admin

Comment: I am guessing the "!" points in the code I had before were checking for the "not" part you are talking about? I have removed them, and my code is now working fine. Only other thing now is my WebView is displaying over the top of the settings button I have on my app. This is only on my tablet though, and not on my mobile device? Any ideas to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

Use

```
if(mUsername.getText().toString().equals("admin") && mPassword.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
```

insted of

```
if(!mUsername.getText().toString().equals("admin") && !mPassword.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
```

from if condition remove !

Comment: Thanks you so much! Only reason I put the "!" points in there is because I followed a tutorial and it told me to do this! Unfortunately I do not have enough "reputation" on stackoverflow as yet,so I cannot upvote your answer. But thanks the same!